# Aws cognito sms delivery success in logs but not received by the user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have created an application where I am adding users from aws lambda function to Cognito and also mapping the users to a group.

I didn't get any error, While creating users on aws cognito.
I have configured aws cognito to send sms when a new user created.

Sms is not received by some numbers but checking the logs it's marked as delivered.

Please have a look at the below log which confirms that message is received by the user but it's not really delivered.

Cognito Region: US WEST(Oregon)

```
{
       "notification": {
           "messageId": "8e7158eb-64dd-53f6-82aa-xxxxxxxxxxxx", // I have replaced original id characters by x
           "timestamp": "2019-06-04 16:18:29.681"
       },
       "delivery": {
           "phoneCarrier": "AT&T",
           "mnc": 180,
           "destination": "+1310600xxxx", // I have replaced last 4 digit with x here to show code. 
           "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
           "smsType": "Transactional",
           "mcc": 311,
           "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone",
           "dwellTimeMs": 381,
           "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 890698
       },
       "status": "SUCCESS"
   }
```

AWS cognito MFA and Verifications:

[image]

AWS cognito Message Customizations:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many reasons led me to believe that this "issue" seems like an issue only due to AWS's poor logging and response mechanism. The failure and reason should be indicated in the response.

After trying to isolate the issue I understood that applying a request for [SNS spending limit increase](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-sms-spending-limit-increase/) should solve the issue.

You are right, there's no indication that limit exceeding is the true issue, though multiple posts in the subject are pointing to that solution.